# Use ISRs inside a library more elegantly

Tags: c++, interrupt, library, class

At the moment I try to make a library which uses `attachInterrupt(?,?,RISING)` to read a sensor. The article of Nick Gammon on [Calling an ISR from a class](https://gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12983) helped me a lot, but his "Glue routines" get pretty ugly with more than 30 potential Interrupt Pins on the ESP32, which all need their own `static void`. Has anyone got a more elegant idea how to do this "Gluing"?

Comment: Can you give more details about the kind of interrupts you want to handle? Type of board? In general, you will need one glue function _per interrupt_, not necessarily one per interrupt _pin_. This can make a difference if several pins share an interrupt, which is the case for the pin change interrupts on AVR.

Comment: An "Arduino" library, which is ESP32 specific, is a bit problematic. An ESP32 isn't an Arduino at all, strictly speaking.

Comment: How about going more low level? `attachInterrupt()` uses different interrupt types depending on the used pin. Most chips only have 1 or 2 external interrupt pins, so the rest is done via pin change interrupts, which cover a whole port, meaning 1 interrupt for a group of 8 pins. You could configure these interrupts directly via their control registers. Though I'm not sure, how this is organized on an ESP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a matter of efficiency, I would favor chrisl’s advise to use the
platform's low-level interrupts if at all possible. This, however, comes
at the cost of portability: you would need an implementation specialized
for each platform you want to support. If you don't want to or cannot
maintain all this platform-specific code, `attachInterrupt()` may be a
reasonable option.

Then, you will absolutely need all those glue routines: since the
interrupt system calls your handlers with no parameters, you will not be
able to share handlers between interrupts, and you end up with as many
handlers as interrupts you are going to use.

There is, however, an elegant way of creating all these specialized
functions without writing them explicitly: you can ask the compiler to
write them for you on the basis of a *template* you provide.

Below is a version of Nick Gammon's example code modified to use a
*template class*. Note that you do not necessarily need a class to use
templates: you could use *template functions* as interrupt handlers if
that is appropriate for your use case.

```cpp
template <uint8_t pin>
class myClass
{
    static volatile bool switchChanged;

public:
    static void begin()
    {
        pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
        attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin),
                        switchPressed, FALLING);
    }

    static void switchPressed()
    {
        switchChanged = true;
    }
};

template <uint8_t pin>
volatile bool myClass<pin>::switchChanged;

myClass<2> foo;
myClass<3> bar;

void setup()
{
    foo.begin();
    bar.begin();
}

void loop(){}
```

Note also that `myClass<2>` and `myClass<3>` are two different classes:
you actually have a different class for each pin. This means that
`foo::switchChanged` and `bar::switchChanged` are two different class
members even though both are `static`. Since you should (in principle)
have at most one instance of each pin-specific class, you can make
everything within the class `static`.

The main caveat of this method is that the pin numbers have now to be
compile-time constants. The great advantage is that you will have a
class created for each interrupt that is actually *used*: no need for an
array of 32 instances on an ESP32 if only a handful of interrupt pins
are going to be actually used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works brilliant for me. I mostly got what you did, but there's one question left: Why do we have to initialize our private `volatile bool myClass<pin>::switchChanged;` outside the class definition?

Comment: It's not an initialization, it's a definition. Static class members are _declared_ within the class definition but have to be _defined_ outside of it. Otherwise you get the link-time error “_undefined reference to `myClass<(unsigned char)2>::switchChanged`_” (and the same for `myClass<3>`).